# How to check if NodeJS is connected to a MySQL server or a MariaDB server?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb

So here is the thing: My program used the `json` type in MySQL, which in MariaDB, would be translated as LONGTEXT. This created a problem since the client is returning a string instead of a JSON Object when querying from a MariaDB server. How could I check if the server is MySQL or MariaDB, so I can manually do parsing when connected to MariaDB?

I am using `mysql2` as the connector.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my own question...

```
mysqlServerVer=mysqlConn._handshakePacket.serverVersion.toLowerCase();
if(mysqlServerVer.indexOf("mariadb") !== -1){
//MariaDB
}
```